# .htaccess rewrite url not work without prefix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite my simple url from

*www.marcoingraiti.it/page.php?page=servizi-di-web-design*

to  *www.marcoingraiti.it/servizi-di-web-design/* ...

and I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This does not works, but if I add prefix

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

and type *www.marcoingraiti.it/page/servizi-di-web-design/*

that syntax works.

Why? my first code is logically right, I don't understand because server says:

> not found.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Based on solely this information, I see no reason why this should happen. Have you tried restarting Apache?

Comment: How does "not work" materialize in error/log messages or behaviour problems? And btw, almost noone has any business using `RewriteBase`.

Comment: @mario RewriteBase seems to be required for .htaccess to work with some hosting providers.

Comment: this is a error: - marcoingraiti.it - AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /web/htdocs/www.marcoingraiti.it/home/servizi-di-web-design (None could be negotiated)., referer http://www.marcoingraiti.it/

Comment: @Anonymous Perhaps. It's probably quirky FCGI handler paths, or elaborate vhost templating issues, if. To me it always looks like verbatimly copied from some tutorial. Just like the `/absolute` rewrite target; which often leads to internal redirects.

Comment: do you have the Symlink option in + ? `Options +FollowSymlinks` before `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: I solve my issue with search by google. the solution is this line: Options -Multiviews

Comment: @MarcoIngraiti add the solution as a self-answer for people with problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The correct RegEx to catch any value in a parameter is

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?page=$1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked: *Why does one work when the other fails?*

Comment: Sorry this is not the answer for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by looping. When you have rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```

then first it matches URI `/servizi-di-web-design/` and then it also matches rewritten URI i.e. `/page.php` and it will keep on matching this and eventually you will get internal server error.

To prevent this behavior you need to use `RewriteCond` as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```